# Install Windows 8 on Macbook by usb drive (without bootcamp)

Tags: windows-8, usb, macbook

I have a macbook pro with **Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger** which *doesnt support bootcamp*, which for me is not a problem because I work in windows. Can anyone tell me, if there is a way to install **Windows 8** using a **USB drive** (**without boot camp**)?? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: There is an article about it: [How To Install Windows 8 From a USB Device](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/install-windows-8-usb.htm)

Comment: Thats for regular pc. Macbook doesnt show the windows usb drive when press ALT at start up

Comment: Doesn't Boot Camp give you the drivers you NEED for Windows to run on Apple hardware? Or are these available in Windows drivers? Can anyone verify this?

Comment: @SeanWebber - The version of Bootcamp supported by OS X 10.4 does not support Windows 8.  Furthermore Bootcamp is not supported by OS X 10.4 per the author's question.  If the drive is bootable it should be able to just install Windows over OS X.

Comment: @Ramhound: "If the drive is bootable it should be able to just install Windows over OS X." +1, but without BootCamp can you tell him where he might get the drivers for Win8 separately?

Comment: @Karan - Drivers might not exist in a case like this.  As I don't have access to an old mac with an unknown configuration I wouldn't be able to locate them either.